# Why does this regular expression only find the last available match?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

1. I know you shouldn't, in general, use Regex with HTML. I am using it as a one time tool to strip some data quickly out of a file that has a constant pattern and it will never be used again. I want to use Regex for this task. **I understand that you should not parse HTML with Regex.**
2. No I do not want to use an XMl Parser, BeautifulSoup, lxml, etc. Thank you. :)
3. I only want to get this one time use out of this, and be done with it forever.

That being said, the regular expression I wrote only matches the last "match" out of the file. I'm not sure why. The file has a fairly constant pattern:

```
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My Title - </b> My Description</p>
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My 2nd Title - </b> My 2nd Description</p>
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My 3rd Title - </b> My 3rd Description</p>
<p class="normal" style="margin-left:1"><b style="font-weight:400">Another one </b>The cake is a lie</p>
```

I don't care about the attributes. I'm trying to group what is in the `<b>` tags and what follows. Title and description.

```
def parseData(html):
    pattern = re.compile('.*<p.*><b.*>(.+)</b>(.+)</p>.*')

    matches = re.findall(pattern, str(html))

    for match in matches:
        print(match)

def main():
    htmlFile = "myFile.htm"

    browser = UrlBrowser()

    parseData(browser.getHTML(htmlFile))
```

This pattern is only matching the last available "match" - I tried adding a `.*` before to see if that would be the issue, but it didn't make a difference. What am I missing on the regex?

Comment: it seems to work : http://fiddle.re/mrban

Comment: "I understand that you should not parse HTML with Regex."  And yet you're messing with them instead of something like `[elem.next + elem.next.next for elem in soup.find_all("b")]`, which would have taken less time to type than it took for you to post the question.. ;^)  You seem to be under the impression that using regex will be inelegant but quick to get working, but this question itself suggests otherwise.

Comment: It wasn't really a matter of "what is quickest and easiest" to get working, it was more of "I want to try it out and see what I can do with it, even though it's messy." I did end up playing around with BeautifulSoup, but ultimately I ended up doing it a different way altogether separate from HTML related or regular expressions. (I did learn quite a bit about why it's said **not** to use regular expressions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. See this [working demo](https://eval.in/50433)

```
matches = re.findall(r'<b[^>]+>(.*?)</b>(.*?)</p>', str)
```

Regular expression:

```
<b            match start of tag '<b'
 [^>]+        any character except: '>' (1 or more times)
 >            match enclosed '>'
 (            group and capture to \1:
  .*?         any character except \n (0 or more times)
 )            end of \1
 </b>         match '</b>'
 (            group and capture to \2:
  .*?         any character except \n (0 or more times)
 )            end of \2
 </p>         match '</p>'
```

You are using `.*` which is greedy (matching the most amount possible). You want to add `?` to the end of that making it a non greedy (matching the least amount possible)

Taking the explanation from the `re` documentation discussing the following quantifiers `?`, `+?`, `??`

> The *, '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
>   text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE
>   <.*> is matched against '<H1>title</H1>', it will match the entire
>   string, and not just '<H1>'. Adding '?' after the qualifier makes it
>   perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters
>   as possible will be matched. Using .*? in the previous expression will
>   match only '<H1>'.

Comment: Can you show it *not* working? That's what I'm trying to work out.

Comment: This did indeed work. I just looked at the input I was getting from the response and looks like the tags didn't come through all 100% correctly from the `response.read`. Can you explain the changes to the expression? I'm trying to improve my understanding of regex.

Answer (score 1):

It's your leading .* that's causing the last-match.  The * and + qualifiers will match as many as possible of the preceding item while still producing a match

Use the "non-greedy" *? in place of each *, and +? in place of each + to get the shortest possible sequence that produces a match.

See: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: I don't think that's it, without the `.*` it still only caught the last match.

Comment: `'.*?<p.*?><b.*?>(.+?)</b>(.+?)</p>.*?'` seems to work just fine for me (Python 3.3)

Answer (score 0):

Something more is happening.

```
import re

data = """\
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My Title - </b> My Description</p>
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My 2nd Title - </b> My 2nd Description</p>
<p someAttribute="yes"><b someOtherAttribute="no">My 3rd Title - </b> My 3rd Description</p>
<p class="normal" style="margin-left:1"><b style="font-weight:400">Another one </b>The cake is a lie</p>"""

print(*re.findall('.*<p.*><b.*>(.+)</b>(.+)</p>.*', data), sep="\n")
#>>> ('My Title - ', ' My Description')
#>>> ('My 2nd Title - ', ' My 2nd Description')
#>>> ('My 3rd Title - ', ' My 3rd Description')
#>>> ('Another one ', 'The cake is a lie')
```

Note that you don't need the `.*` at the start and end:

```
print(*re.findall('<p.*><b.*>(.+)</b>(.+)</p>', data), sep="\n")
#>>> ('My Title - ', ' My Description')
#>>> ('My 2nd Title - ', ' My 2nd Description')
#>>> ('My 3rd Title - ', ' My 3rd Description')
#>>> ('Another one ', 'The cake is a lie')
```

'Cause the Regex already searches the whole string for matches.

You might also want to prefer non-greedy repeats, but I don't think that's the problem:

```
print(*re.findall('<p.*?><b.*?>(.+?)</b>(.+?)</p>', data), sep="\n")
#>>> ('My Title - ', ' My Description')
#>>> ('My 2nd Title - ', ' My 2nd Description')
#>>> ('My 3rd Title - ', ' My 3rd Description')
#>>> ('Another one ', 'The cake is a lie')
```